# derefencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c

I am new to C programming.

So this is in my header file

```
typedef struct Rec *node;
```

This is in my c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

typedef struct Rec *List;
typedef struct Listing{

    node *items;
    int numelems;
    struct List *next;

}Listing;

int sum(List L)
{
    if(L->items == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return (L->head + sum(L->tail));
}

int main(void)
{
    return 1;
}
```

I am getting this error where it says
dereferencing pointer to incomplete type at `if(L->items == NULL)`.
I know that it is in my struct but I do not know how to fix it. I tried trial and error however I would like to understand what and where my error is.

PS: this program is just for myself learning.

Comment: What's in `header.h`?  Does it define `struct Rec` or `struct List`?  If not, that's the trouble — your `List` parameter is a `struct Rec *`, and if you've not defined `struct Rec` anywhere, you have problems.  Your `struct Listing` contains a `struct List *` which is a pointer to a different type too.  Note that in your code, the `List` type is unrelated to the `struct List` type.

Comment: `typedef struct Rec *node;` - **no no no no please no!** Don't hide pointers behind (misleadingly differently named) `typedef`s!

Answer (score 0):

If the only item in your header is `typedef struct Rec *node;`, then that's the trouble. 
You've not defined `struct Rec` or `struct List` anywhere.  You've said they exist, but that's all.  That makes them incomplete types, and you can't dereference an incomplete structure type because the compiler doesn't know what members are in an incomplete structure type.

Your `List` parameter is a `struct Rec *` in disguise, and if you've not defined `struct Rec` anywhere, you have problems. Your `struct Listing` contains a `struct List *` which is a pointer to a different type too. Note that in your code, the `List` type is unrelated to the `struct List` type.  And note that `node` and `List` are both aliases for the type `struct Rec *`.

Your code in `sum()` references a `head` and `tail` member of the `List` structure pointer, so your `struct Rec` needs to contain those names.

In general, it is best to keep structure tags and `typedef` names closely related.  That is:

```
typedef struct Node Node;
```

but not:

```
typedef struct Angel Elephant;
```

Also, the general consensus is that it is best not to embed pointers in the `typedef`.  That is, it is OK to write the `typedef`s above, but not OK to use:

```
typedef struct Fish *Fish;
```

For example, see [Is it a good idea to `typedef` pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)